# convert form.showDialog from vb to Java

Tags: java, vb.net

I need a similar code of form.showDialog from vb to Java to show a Frame up to its parent Frame. I've tried something like this :

```
 private void button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        Frame2 form = new Frame2();
        form.setVisible(true);
 }
```

and i got 2 problems,
the first : the new frame wont stay on the top alway, that mean i can select the old form
and the second problem : when i close the new form the parent form will close too !

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Swing's [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Frame,%20boolean%29) which has a modal property allowing the dialog to remain as the topmost window

Comment: and how to show my frame as a dialog with JDialog ?

Comment: create the dialog setting the modal flag as true, then call `dialog.setVisible(true)` (although I'd recommend using a `JFrame` instead for consistency)